# Selenium Webdriver Python растет потребление ОЗУ

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

Краткая история. Сделал себе бота-парсера на хроме, который логинится на определенный сайт и парсит ссылки. Поместил это все в while true: try: except:, чтобы при возникновении ошибки круг продолжал работу. Насчет озу она после каждой ошибки и нового старта круга увеличивает потребление на 20-50мб, что забивает мой сервер спустя пару часов активной работы с 6-ю аккаунтами. Прочитал статью ниже

> "Для кеша нет прямого способа сделать это через Selenium. Если вы пытаетесь убедиться, что все очищено в начале запуска драйвера Chrome или когда вы закончите, вам не нужно ничего делать. Каждый раз, когда вы инициализируете веб-драйвер, это новый экземпляр без кеша, файлов cookie или истории. Каждый раз, когда вы отключаете драйвер, все это очищается."

и поместил в except Exceptions команду для закрытия браузера driver.close() , проверил отключением параметра -headless и оно работало, но колво потребляемой озу в процессе увеличивался , как обычно. Можете подсказать решение проблемы или костыль, который например будет раз в час перезапускать мой скрипт?
P.s через диспетчер задач потребление увеличивается именно у процесса chrome.exe
Ниже прикрепил скриншот примера часовой работы и только что запущенного скрипта [image: 1]

Comment: Это нормально, браузеры давно уж начали хотеть много гигабайт памяти

Comment: Убивайте не нужные объекты вручную, del object